# estimating the value of pi using the monte carlo method, I am using radius as 1,I dont get the value of pi, increasing the iterations doesnt change it

Tags: c, montecarlo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double getRandomNumber(double lower_limit, double upper_limit){
    double random = ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX;
    double range = (upper_limit - lower_limit) * random;
    return (range + lower_limit);
}

double calculatePi(int max_iteration){
    int inside = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double vector = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < max_iteration; i++){
        x = getRandomNumber(0,2);
        y = getRandomNumber(0,2);
        vector = x*x+y*y;
        if(vector <= 1){
            inside++;
        }
    }
    return (4.0 * inside) / max_iteration;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Mean Value of 100 Estimated Pi's = %lf", calculatePi(100));
    return 0;
}
```

even if I try increasing the iteration number I dont get the correct answer and I cant debug my code, I get a value of around 0.8 yet I multiply the return value by 4

Comment: You're generating random numbers from 0 to 2. It should be from -1 to 1.

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/estimating-value-pi-using-monte-carlo/#